# Regex remove last part

Tags: regex

If I have this:

```
2.2.3.140113
```

and do this:

```
$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(str), '^(\d+)\.(.+)$', '$1_$2' ) )">
```

I will get this:

```
2_2.3.140113
```

What I want is that it should be

```
2_2.3
```

How do I remove the last part?

Comment: Do you have more sample strings?

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex to:

```
^(\d+)\.(.+)\.\d+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following regex:

```
^(\d+)\.(.+)(\.\d+)$
```

It will create third group which you will just ignore, so:

```
$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(str), '^(\d+)\.(.+)(\.\d+)$', '$1_$2' ) )">
```

Answer (score 1):

So you shouldn't capture the rest of them:

```
$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(str), '^(\d+)\.(.+?\..+?)\..*', '$1_$2' ) )">
```

Updated:

*There's no need to use `$` as your regex includes all characters at the end*

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aA2pW6)

Comment: It doesn't seem you tested the regex part either. There [are no matches at all](http://regex101.com/r/gP5jN6)!

Comment: ^(\d+)\.(.+?\..+?)\. becomes  2_2.3121221

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(str), '^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$', '$1_$2.$3' ) )">
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, something like this won't do it?

```
^(\d+)\.(\d+\.\d+).*
```

Replace to:

```
$1_$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but if you want all numbers before the final one you can do:

```
(\d+)(?=\.)
```

[image]

This will capture all number groups that are followed by a dot (.)